# What IOS version to use in cordova testing?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have been building apps only for android for quit a while now, and this not the point of using a hybrid platform :D.

What I am looking on is a version slimier to android kitkat when cordova started to use the webview component instead of native browser. But I can't tell when that happened with IOS -**This is my actual question, In what IOS version the webview were added?**-

I have been searching for a while and couldn't tell which version to use(some says 4 and some says 8) so that was not really helpful.

ps: It would really help to tell me what do YOU prefer to use.

Thanks :)

Comment: Better to use iOS 9 or greater as latest versions will be more stable and will have issue fixes too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview) UIWebView was added into iOS SDK 2.0. However when developing for iOS it is always best to build for the latest few versions targeting iOS 8+ is a good starting point. Most users on iOS convert to the latest version quickly, currently 93% or so are [on iOS 9 or 10](https://mixpanel.com/trends/#report/ios_10)

Answer (score 1):

I read here few minutes ago, for iPhone Only:

- 10.X     36.1%
- 9.X      57.2%
- 8.X      3.1%

Personnaly i will test my app on ios 9 & 10 only.